# Why I set time but get different?

Tags: android

I have time in milliseconds and I want to convert it hours,minutes and seconds. I've tried this code but I somehow get not current hours.Example:
I set time 3:50 but got 7:50. Why does this happen?

This is how I set,get and display time:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
long alarm3 = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        long alarm4 = (alarm3/(1000*60*60))%24;
        long alarm5 = (alarm3/(1000*60))%60;
        long alarm6 = (alarm3/1000)%60;
Log.i("Alarm1","Hours:" + Long.toString(alarm4));
        Log.i("Alarm1","Minutes:" + Long.toString(alarm5));
        Log.i("Alarm1","Seconds:" + Long.toString(alarm6));
```

Comment: do you set the time using up-down arrows or edit the text itself ?!!

Comment: @muhammed-refaat If you mean which view I use then I use a timepicker. If not then please explain your question

Comment: I know you are using a TimePicker, I'm asking you how you use it to set the time ?!! as the TimePicker can be used in two ways, the first one by (plus/mines) buttons and the second one by android keyboard, so if you use it by android keyboard this might be your problem and then I will explain why.

Comment: @muhammed-refaat Well, I think it's that one with pluses and minuses but I'm not sure cause I use emulator with api level 19 and I don't have any pluses and minuses and all I have to do is just scroll.

Comment: well, that's ok, just keep in mind when you use the keyboard to edit the hour or the minute yourself, it won't reflect until you remove the focus for the something you edit, may be that will help you furthermore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers above will just make it work, you might still wonder why your solution did not. That's most probably because of the time zone offset. When you get the instance of the Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

It inherits your locale, so your time zone too.
Then, assuming your app's timePicker works in the same time zone, you set the minute and hour consistenly:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
```

but at the end this particular method returns a UTC time:

```
long alarm3 = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

So I guess your TZ offset is 4 hours.

Comment: It should not - the alarm gets triggered with the same offset as the app's time, so it's just your logs displaying funny (UTC) time.

Comment: How do you think is it okay that I set alarms using time in mills?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
public static String getOnlyTimeFromMillis(long millis) {
    SimpleDateFormat apiFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date(millis);
    return apiFormat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Function

```
public static String getTimeFromMilliseconds(long milliseconds) {

        return (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date(milliseconds));
    }
```